# Estalished socket at client side cannot be found at server side

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have met such a weird problem.

We use a thread to flush something to a server by http. sometimes the thread seems stuck in recving data from socket.

jstack below:

```
"zipkin-flush-1" #21 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f67f3e64000 nid=0x8b2 runnable [0x00007f67c5ed9000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
- locked <0x000000008ab3bff0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
- locked <0x00000000896148b0> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
- locked <0x00000000896148b0>; (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
```

I have use netstat to monitor socket status at client side,which shows below.

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.X.X.X:42953   ::ffff:10.X.X.X:9441     ESTABLISHED 2099/java
```

well, if I do the same at server side just got nothing show

I cannot understand how this situation happended, any explanation will be appreciated. thanks a lot.

Comment: Port 9441 doesn't show up at the server at all?

Comment: port 9441 can be found at server side, but I cannot find 42593 port

Comment: Is the client connected *directly* to the server, or does it use a proxy? If not proxy, then perhaps the TCP connection got dropped on the server side, and the client machine simply hasn't noticed it yet. Abnormal disconnects can't always be seen on the other side for a (potentially long) while, especially if TCP keepalives are not enabled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not sure if there is a proxy. thanks anyway